# Wire multiple SW-420 Vibration sensors to a single pin

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu

I am working on installing an alarm system using Konnected IO on a NodeMCU esp8266. I have multiple bay widows which will use 4 SW-420 vibration sensors. I would like to wire all 4 of the SW-420 vibration sensors to a single pin. When any of the 4 sensors detect vibration the pin will go to high. I attempted to simply wire the d-outs from all four together and all four sensors stoped working. I'm out of ideas on how to do this any help would be greatly appreciated. I believe sensors send out a low signal when no vibration is detected and high signal when vibration is detected. Link to sensors: [https://www.amazon.com/XLX-Vibration-Normally-Sensitive-High-Efficient/dp/B07V8FJRN1/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V8FJRN1)

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas came to my mind, first is to connect each output to four digital pins and then do something like this:

```
if(digitalRead(pinOne) == HIGH || digitalRead(pinTwo) == HIGH || ...){
do something
}
```

Or you can use an opamp or comparator for that purpose:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWcjaE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In above configuration if any of the sensors output is HIGH, op amp will drag it's output to the positive rail (~5V). otherwise output is LOW (~0 V).